# FLORIS: problems with initializing it

Tags: floris

I have installed FLORIS using pip install in python, and I have imported it with "import". Now how does it work? what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

FLORIS does not currently have explicit user documentation, but there are a series of example scripts that demonstrate basic usage. You can start with running those at https://github.com/NREL/floris/tree/main/examples/_getting_started. Then, take a look at some of the other scripts in the examples folder for more in depth analysis.